# How to add pdf from Github CI environments to repository?

Tags: pdf, latex, github-actions

I add my latek article on GitHub and I'm using this [action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-for-latex) to build the PDF file every time a push is executed. How can I automatically add this PDF file to my project repo ?

Comment: A `run:` step with `git add file.pdf; git commit -m "Add PDF file"; git push`? You might have to set author name and email for the Git config as well.

Comment: this solution came to mind to me too, but I thought a better solution could be found

Comment: I wouldn't know of another way. The [README](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-for-latex#where-is-the-pdf-file-how-to-upload-it) for your action even mentions just using `git` to upload to the repo.